# using Projection in OpenGL using C#?

Tags: c#, opengl, projection, tao-framework

For those who don't know, Tao.opengl, Tao.freeglut are required for the C# console application.

Now, for my problem: my tutor asked us to draw 4 rectangles, so I drew them successfully.

and copy/paste the other codes (which our tutor didn't explain due to time shortage)

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using Tao.OpenGl;

namespace Homework_1
{
    class Triangles
    {
        static void display()
        {
            Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
            Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glEnd();

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
            Gl.glVertex3f(2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glEnd();

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
            Gl.glVertex3f(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(2.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glEnd();

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
            Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glEnd();


            Gl.glFlush();

        }

        static void init()
        {

            Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
            Gl.glLoadIdentity();
            Gl.glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        }

        public static void Main(String[] argv)
        {
            Glut.glutInit();
            Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB);
            Glut.glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
            Glut.glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
            Glut.glutCreateWindow("hello");
            init();
            Glut.glutDisplayFunc(display);
            Glut.glutMainLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

When running the application, all it shows is white, so I'm 100 % sure that the error is inside the init() method I copied and pasted, the line

```
 Gl.glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

I'm 100 % sure Gl.glOrtho's values must be changed, but the problem is, I don't know how to use it.

Please correct my error, so it can show the 4 triangles I've drawn, and a small explanation will make it more obvious and acceptable.

Comment: You should probably read the [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/)  Lots of people complain that they're outdated, but they cover the functions you're using and explain them very well, both how to use them and why.

Comment: So did you solve it yourself or discard the problem or do you still have some unclarities regarding the already posed answers? In the formaer case abandoning a question is extremely bad practice and in the latter case feel free to ask any question you might have on one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply spoken the `glOrtho` call generally determines the area of your world that is visible. So in your case you you only see the [0,1]-square, which is completely covered by the first (white) polygon (that is the [-1,1]-square). So to see all your polygons, you should use e.g.

```
glOrtho(-1.0, 4.0, -1.0, 4.0, -1.0, 1.0);  //or maybe with some margin of +/- 0.1
```

This all gets more difficult when you use a modelview matrix that is not identity or a perspective projection (istead of an orthographic one). I advice you to look a bit more into OpenGL's transformation pipeline for more insight. Maybe the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7377912/743214) help with that.

You also seem to have forgotten to make a call to

```
glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

which determines the region of the framebuffer your view is rendered into and whose extents should usually match the extents of your window. By default a context's viewport matches the size of the window it's attached to, but it is good practice to set the viewport explicitly, especially when the window gets resized, as in this case the viewport is not updated automatically.

And by the way, you don't need to set the color for every polygon if they're all colored the same, as **OpenGL is a state machine**.

Comment: silly question
what does the view port really do?
does it make things I've drawn look in a 3d way?

Comment: @Obzajd No, it just determines how the normalized device coordinates that are in [-1,1] resulting after the projection transform (after the `glOrtho`, if you want) are scaled to make up pixel coordinates. This way the projection transformation and clipping can operate in a generic space (the [-1,1] cube) independent on the actual resolution of the window things get rendered into. So the `glViewport` determines the range of the framebuffer that your world gets rendered into and should usually match the dimensions of your window.

Comment: Great Problem analysis 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`glVertex3` is so deprecated your teacher shouldn't even acknowledge its existence, but well.

```
void glOrtho(GLdouble   left,
             GLdouble   right,
             GLdouble   bottom,
             GLdouble   top,
             GLdouble   nearVal,
             GLdouble   farVal);
```

The first two parameters specify the coordinates for the Left and Right clipping planes. 
The third and fourth parameters specify the coordinates for the Bottom and Top Clipping planes.

With your current glOrtho, the first rectangle covers up the entire screen, and the others cover the screen, also. Combined with your GlColor3f setting the drawing color to White, your entire screen becomes white. You don't need to respecify it, by the way.

A way of having it work would be to have a glOrtho like this :

```
 Gl.glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

You could also modifiy your glVertex methods to draw a smaller rectangle.

Comment: WOW
you simply seem the OpenGL encyclopedia!