# How Does OpenGL's Coordinate System Work?

Tags: opengl, glut

this is probably a pretty basic question but I can't seem to get OpenGL to work with a point coordinate system. Instead it seems to be in percents, for example .99 puts me right at the edge of the screen. Is this how it is, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

code used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

void RenderScene()
{
    glLoadIdentity (); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin( GL_POINTS );  

        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );

    glEnd();


    glFlush();  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );                
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );        
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );        
    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" );   
    glutDisplayFunc( RenderScene );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7377912/743214) will provide you some insight into OpenGL's transformation pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL works in the following way: You start of a local coordinate system (of arbitrary units). This coordinate system is transformed to so called **eye space** coordinates by the *model-view* matrix (it is called model-view matrix, because it combines model and view transformations).

The eye space is then transformed to **clip space** by the *projection* matrix, immediately followed by the *perspective divide* to obtain **normalized device coordinates** ( `NDC{x,y,z} = Clip{x,y,z}/Clip_w` ). The range [-1,1]^3 in **NDC** space is mapped to the viewport (x and y) and the set depth range (z).

So if you leave your transformation matrices (*modelview* and *projection*) identity, then indeed the coordinate ranges [-1,1] will map to the Viewport. However by choosing appropriate transformation and projection you can map from Model Space units to Viewport units arbitrarily.

Comment: Are you sure about Clip{x,y,z}/Clip_w ? What if I have my triangles at Z=1000. Are they thrown away? Isn't it division first, clipping after htat?

Comment: @IvanKuckir: The OpenGL specification defines that clipping happens before the homogenous divide.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a percentage: it's related to the size and aspect ratio of your current viewport. I could write a whole story about it, but I'd suggest you take a look at [NeHe's tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) on OpenGL, starting with [lesson 1](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) about setting up the window. Very thorough, and highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the projection matrix concept.

Essentially, a projection matrix is matrix that projects a vertex on a 2D space. There are two projection matrices: perspective and orthographic.

The current projection matrix determine the effective vertex screen position. Since you do not set the projection matrix, you are using the default one, which is the orthographic, with horizontal and vertical range -1 .. +1.

To control the projection matrix, see gluOrtho2D function. There you can find all information required.