# GluProject not working... If the object haves Z=-1.0f and it is scaled to (0.01f,0.01f,0.0f) which parameters I have to pass to GluProject?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Until now, I worked with `gluProject`, perspective projection, and a zoomable square centered on the screen with a lower left vertex (-1,-1,0). I zoom the square adjusting the Z axis.

For example, I zoomed the square to Z=-5, and I call `gluProject` with the openGL object parameters (-1,-1,0) to know the window pixels X,Y position of that vertex of the square. It works fine.

But now, I changed my architecture, and now I'm not using Z to zoom, I'm scaling to zoom. I have the square at Z=-1.0f, and initially it is scaled to (0.01f,0.01f,0.0f), is a small square.

Which X,Y,Z values do I have to pass to `gluProject`? I'm passing -1,-1,0, and `gluProject` is giving me erroneous x,y outPutCoords values, (-101.774124,-226.27419)

Comment: Showing your transformation code might help to solve your problem. Are you using `glScale` or are you really rendering the polygon using (0.01, 0.01, 0)? In the former case, keep im mind not to scale with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Again and again and again:** `gluProject` does exactly the same thing like the OpenGL transformation pipeline (if called with OpenGL's matrices and viewport, of course). So whatever vertices you send to OpenGL, these are the vertices you have to put into `gluProject`.

If you render the polygon using the vertex (-1,-1,0), then you have to call `gluProject` with this vertex. Every other transformation (be it translation, scaling, rotation, or whatever) comes from the transformation matrices. But if you indeed render the polygon using the vertex (0.01, 0.01, 0), then you have to put this into `gluProject`.

Make sure you completely understand the OpenGL transformation pipeline (the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7377912/743214) may help) and the workings of `gluProject` before continuing to use it and posting questions for every little input that you think gives wrong results.