# Disable/skip vertex in shader

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, shader, webgl, vertex

I am rendering a huge point cloud (1.5 Mio. points) as GLPoints with WebGL and naturally encounter performance issues.

So my first idea is limit the amount of points be drawn on the screen. Especially points far away from the camera are "useless" and should not be rendered.

I went about it by calculating the distance between any point and the camera. In my vertex shader I would like to only render the points "close" enough to the camera. So far I try to skip them if the distance "s" is in between the camera and a clipping plane (hence negative).

```
if( s < 0.0){
  gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  frontColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 0.0;
}else{
  gl_Position = ps_ProjectionMatrix * ecPos4;
}
```

However, instead of completely skipping the vertex it is still rendered (even if I don't see it) as I can tell by the FPS displayed.
Is there a way to completely disable/skip/"delete" a vertex within a vertex shader?

---

I can see how frustum culling would help speed things up. To clearify things, when should the culling take place? Since the culling has to be recalculated after every camera movement, should I put in my main loop? However doing 1 Mio. calculations in the render loop does not seem to be a very good idea.

Do I understand it correctely that once my camera looks in totally different direction than my points these should be clipped automatically by WebGl/the hardware? Yet, I get the feeling that looking "away" does not help. (FPS did not go up) Can someone please elaborte a bit!

The engine that I use has a default perspective projection matrix. Obiviously it affects the coordinates of every vertex. How does the projection matrix relate to the auto clipping?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Hi Christian. I read it, but it does not go into detail about the etiquett. Apparently one is not supposed to greet or thank other users? Is that correct?

Comment: Not that strictly, but it bloats the question with unneccessary chatter. But I wasn't referring to this in my comment. I just wanted to make sure you are aware of the workings of the site as newbies sometimes tend to mistake it for a forum. Sorry if my comment confused you, your question is actually not so bad.

Comment: See my comments on both answers. Software frustum culling is definitely no solution for your problem. Just let OpenGL's hardware view frustum clipping after the vertex stage do its job. And by the way, this is no answer and should either be a comment or an appendage to the original question.

Comment: You just need to adjust the projection matrix to get a tighter far-plane. If you don't know how to do it, or what a far plane is, then delve a little deeper into basic 3d computer graphics, especially transformations.

Comment: If looking away does not help, then the rendering is just not fill-limited, but geometry-limited or CPU-limited or bandwidth-limited. In this case hardware view volume clipping won't help anyway. But software view frustum culling will itselfs be very CPU-heavy and has a large impact on batching, which in turn raises the CPU-heaviness, but may reduce bandwidth-problems.

Comment: I would like to advise you to use a spacial partitioning method - perhaps a quadtree? If you group these points within appropriate nodes within a quadtree you can simply cull out some axis aligned bounding boxes and you're through. All this can be done on CPU without a substantial hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to tweak your projection matrix, so that your view frustum culls out those points that are too far away to meaningfully contribute to your image.  This [tutorial from lighthouse3d](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/) provides a description of the viewing frustum, and describes methods for implementing frustum-based culling in software.  Note that this is not necessary in your case, since OpenGL does it for you, provided you've set up your projection matrix appropriately.

Comment: Good point, not thought about that. The most simle things always come to mind last.

Comment: I think the link to a tutorial on software view frustum culling is a bit misleading, since  all that needs to be done is to simply adjust his projection matrix to let OpenGL's view volume clipping do the culling for him after the vertex shader stage. If you indeed speak of software frustum culling, then this won't work in his case, as it would definitely be too inefficient to test each point, not to speak of the impact on batching.

Comment: You are right, Christian.  I don't think that I examined the tutorial closely -- I simply saw the frustum explanation at the head.  I simply meant what I said in the first sentence, and what you have suggested here: adjust the projection matrix.  I've will edit the answer.

Comment: I adjusted the projection matrix and now I the "auto"-clipping of OpenGL works as advertised. Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no there isn't. You cannot discard vertices entirely. What would a triangle of two vertices be (when you discarded the third)? You could do it on a per-primitive basis using the geometry shader, but that is IMHO not supported in WebGL. Even if you only draw point primitives, the vertex shader still has no notion of any primitives and cannot just discard vertices.

What you can do is move the vertex outside of the viewing volume. This way it gets clipped away and you only have to pay for the vertex shader and neither for rasterization (which wouldn't cost much anyway when using points of size 1) nor for the fragment shader.

That seems to be what you want to do at the moment, but it is actually not a good idea to set a vertex' w coordinate to 0, which results in undefined behaviour during perspective division. Just set it to be outside of the canonical view volume (the [-1,1] cube):

```
if( s < 0.0 )
    gl_Position = vec4(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
else
    gl_Position = ps_ProjectionMatrix * ecPos4;
```

You also don't need to mess with `gl_PointSize`. Setting it's position outside the viewing volume is enough.

**EDIT:** But in your case the solution from James' answer is much easier. Just change the far plane of your projection matrix, whose task is exactly to clip away too far objects.

Comment: @Tom Nobody spoke of software frustum culling. As you should know, OpenGL performs view frustum clipping after the vertex shader stage and before rasterization and fragment shader. So to get too far points clipped away automatically just set the vertex position outside of the view volume in the shader (the [-1,1] cube), like shown above. Or even easier and without any effort, just adjust the far clipping plane of the view volume by adjusting your projection matrix apropriately, like James suggested. Maybe his link to a software frustum culling tutorial was misleading.

Comment: Thanky for the refinded explaination. There is one more thing that I don't quite understand just yet. What do you mean by "the [-1,1] cube". Isn't the gl_Position supposed to be a vec4?

Comment: With [-1,1] cube I mean a box which spans from -1 to 1 in x, y and z. Your viewing volume (the visible scene) is (or should be) transformed into this in the vertex shader stage (and the follwoing perspective division). Everything outside of this volume is clipped away. To gain some more insight into OpenGL's transformation pipeline, the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7377912/743214) may help.

Comment: Thank you! The link has been very helpful.