# difference between gl_position and varying variable?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Hi all I am new to OpenGL ES 2.0 . I am confused with gl_position and varying variable both will be the output from vertex shader. varying variable will be passed to fragment shader, what about gl_position. Does gl_position influence on varying variable in fragment shader.
gl_position=vec4(-1); what is the meaning of this.
PLease do help me to understand these things in a much better way.

Answer (score 3):

gl_Position is special variable. It is used to calculate which fragment will fragment shader be calculating/shading (it calculates its position). All other varyings are directly interpolated across the primitive.

gl_Position is not available in fragment shader. But there is gl_FragCoord variable available which is calculated from gl_Position so, that x/y values of it changes from 0 to 1 (from one screen side to another), z is depth from 0 (near plane) to 1 (far plane). And w is something like 1/gl_Position.w (feel free to look what it is exactly in OpenGL|ES2 spec).

Comment: Well, It doesn't calculate a fragment's position. It just calculates the vertex' clip space position. That is in turn interpolated across the primitive like any other varying (although also used for clipping). So it can be seen as a special builtin varying variable. And by the way, `gl_FragCoord.xy` is not in [0,1] but in window coordinates (pixels).

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks a lot for the replay ya it calculates the vertex clip space position, means after that space the output will not be displayed is this the meaning?. SO varying means we find the value for the vertex , for which color will be applied in fragment shader is this the meaning?. gl_position=vec4(-1) what is the meaning of this.? Please do help me.

Comment: @Megharaj The clip space is the space in which the view volume clipping is done. The view volume in turn is the [-1,1] cube in clip space. A varying is a variable that is output by the vertex shader and interpolated across the primitive to gain the fragments' values, like the color, or the vertex position whose interpolation results in the individual pixels (or rather fragment positions) to be rendered.

Comment: @Megharaj I think you lack some fundamental understanding of the graphics pipeline, hard to answer in a comment (or I'm just too stupid to understand your questions). Some more introductory material might help. Or look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7377912/743214) to gain some more undertsanding of OpenGL's transformation pipeline.

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks a lot for your help i will go through it.