# OpenGL Incorrect glRasterPos position

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

So I'm playing around with OpenGL and drawing bitmaps and it seems at times glRasterPos is off by a pixel. When I get the GL_CURRENT_RASTERPOSITION I can see that rouding (floor) is causing this error. For example when I set the x-pos to 110 it results in 109.9998 which leads the bitmap to be drawn on pixel 109. Any ideas why I can't draw to pixel 110? See example and output below:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluOrtho2D(0, 800, 800, 0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);

glRasterPos2f (100.0, 12);
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos);
printf("%f\n",pos[0]);

glRasterPos2f (110.0, 30.0);
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos);
printf("%f\n",pos[0]);

glRasterPos2f (111.0, 45);
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos);
printf("%f\n",pos[0]);


Console Output:
    100.000000
    109.999992
    111.000015
```

UPDATE: It seems to have to do with the Ortho2D and the glViewport values I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `glRasterPos2i` instead and specify integer coordinates.

Comment: Won't help, since this will just change the API to accept integers. But those integers will still run (as floats) through the same pipeline that causes those rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to have to do with the Ortho2D and the glViewport values I am
>   using.

In fact it does. While your current `glOrtho/glViewport` configuration lets you specify coordinates directly in window (viewport) space and thus as pixels, they are still converted into normalized device coordinates ([-1,1]) and back when running through the pipeline. So this is the point where you get in rounding errors.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16566702/743214) and its answers for some thoughts about using OpenGL for pixel-perfect rendering and why this is not as easy as it may seem at first. Though I don't completely know how this actually applies to the deprecated pixel drawing functions (which nobody ever uses anyway).